# Mosquitto server not able to connect from outside network

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I followed the TLS configuration on official Mosquitto website and generated all the certificates and keys.

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

listener 1883

port 8883

cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/server.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/server.key

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

It is working fine locally. but I am not able to connect from outside my network. Can someone explain me what wrong I am doing here ? AM i missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to tell us more about your network, is this a home broadband setup? Have you set up port forwarding? What address are you trying to connect to? What errors are you getting? Did it work before you set up the certificates?

Comment: It is not a home broadband. It is a hosted server which I am able to access using putty with the server ip and port 22. I did open the ports for 1883 and 8883. I just get a timeout when i try to access it. I am able to access within the network for each port but when i access outside the network it shows timeout. So, I do not know should i have to setup client certificates also ? what i actually did was i installed mosquitto broker on my laptop and tried to subscribe using mosquitto_sub -h xx.xx.xx.xx -t test -p 8883 . so it gave me a timeout

Comment: You say you've opened the ports, where? In the hosting portal or in the firewall on the VM?

Comment: Does binding 2 ports work? :O